# Hide MenuView on Cell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a button on cell On click of this button I want to open a view, which work fine. Now problem is when we click on next cell button, my previous view doesn't hides.
Here is what I am trying two way but not work. Please help .

```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustumCellTableViewCell";

            CustumCellTableViewCell *cell = (CustumCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustumCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

             cell.touchButton.tag =indexPath.row;
            [cell.touchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(menuButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            cell.menuView.hidden = YES;


            return cell;
        }



        - (void) menuButtonClick:(id) sender

        {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
                CustumCellTableViewCell *cell=(CustumCellTableViewCell *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

            if (cell.menuView.hidden) {
                cell.menuView.hidden = NO;
            } else {
                cell.menuView.hidden = YES;
            }
    1 method
    for ( CustumCellTableViewCell *cell1 in table.visibleCells ) {

            NSLog(@"%@",cell1);
            if (cell1 != cell) {
                cell.menuView.hidden = YES;
            }

        }

2 method

for (NSIndexPath *indexpaths in  [table indexPathsForVisibleRows] ) {

        if (indexpaths == indexPath) {

            cell.menuView.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
           cell.menuView.hidden = YES;
        }


    }


         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [for ( CustumCellTableViewCell *cell1 in \[table visibleCells\] ) {


            if (cell1 != cell) {
                cell1.menuView.hidden = YES;
            }
            else
            {
                cell1.menuView.hidden = NO;
            }

        }][1]


  [1]: http://
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using currently selected cell. If you want to hide last selected cell menu than you have to store **last selected cell index**.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastSelectedCell inSection:0];
        CustumCellTableViewCell *cell=(CustumCellTableViewCell *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
cell.menuView.hidden = YES;

/*
 your code goes here
*/

lastSelectedCell = [sender tag];
```

Comment: can we not workonfor ( CustumCellTableViewCell *cell1 in table.visibleCells ) {

        NSLog(@"%@",cell1);
        if (cell1 != cell) {
            cell.menuView.hidden = YES;
        }

    }

Comment: Yes, you can. The Problem was that it was not hiding correct cell menu. I have shown you the one way to hide correct cell menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can add cell tag with indexPath.row and compare cell.tag is equal to [sender tag] or not. Also check your sender tag value is correct or not.

```
   - (void) menuButtonClick:(id) sender
    {

    [table reloadData];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];

    CustumCellTableViewCell *cell=(CustumCellTableViewCell *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

    if(cell.tag==[sender tag]){

          cell.menuView.hidden = NO;
     } else {

          cell.menuView.hidden = YES;
     }

  }
```